If $g(x)=\sum_{=1}^{\infty}x_⋅2^{−}$, why $g(1000...)$ and $g(0111...)$ are both equal to 1/2?

$\sum_{=1}^{\infty}x_⋅2^{−}$

I stumbled across this formula in a paper about cardinality of sets and I don't understand why these two expansions are the same.
Shouldn't the series be: $1\times1/2+0\times(2^-0) \cdots$ or $1 \times 1/2+2 \times 2/2 \cdots$?

Please use MathJax to format equations. Please put the question in the main body and not just into the title.

I have attempted to better your presentation. Is it correct with $x_n$ the "bicimals" of x. But I dont understand your series inside the question.

It looks to me the same as the recurring question usually asked in base ten : is 0.99999... (with an infinite number of $9$) the same as $1.00000$ ?Answer : yes

I just found the same question here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491967/how-to-understand-dyadic-expansion
But still I don't get that last step

@JeanMarie I think I get your point, I just would like somebody to tell me how to write the series right in order to get those results

@JeanMarie  I mean, is it supposed to mean that the two series both converge to 1/2? But how should I write them?

That's right : see my answer.

Let me introduce a "bicimal point" in order to work on "realistic numbers" by writing the (plain !) binary decomposition :
$$x=0.10000...=1 \times 2^{-1}\tag{1}$$
to be compared with the binary decomposition :
$$x'=0.01111... = 0 \times 2^{-1}+1\times 2^{-2}+1\times 2^{-3}+1\times 2^{-4}+...$$
where we recognize a geometric series with first term and ratio equal to $2^{-1}$ whose sum is precisely (1).

GOT IT, I was making a stupid mistake. THANKS A LOT!!!
